# JQuery Lightbox- confine overlay to specific div - not whole page

Tags: jquery, css

Have spent days trying to figure this, but maybe is not possible.

I am using jquery lightbox and a seperate main page navigation for multiple galleries each with a lighbox feature.

I would like to nest the jquery lightbox overlay within a div  so it does not cover the whole window but only relates to the div it is in?

Reason being -  I would like the main Navigation to be accessible without clicking on the overlay and I want the lightbox content to stay within set parameters ( i.e. the container for the page), not move around when different screen resolutions are used and thus not be aligned with main navigation bar and headings.

Any advice re: jquery script, addons,  to use to make this possible, if at all possible. 
Or other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Mamj, if my response was helpful to you, please click the checkbox next to my post so it turns green.  Thank you.

Comment: I suppose that this is *hackable*. Can you give a link to the lightbox you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll likely have to do away with the lightbox plugin's provided overlay and do your own.

The process of creating an overlay is simple.  I could reinvent the wheel here, or I can just send you something like this blog post: http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/

See that overlay div with a class of `#overlay`?  All you should need to do to make it size to a container is put that overlay div within that container and set the container style `position: relative`.

You can choose to ignore all of that post's implementation on the JavaScript side and replace it with your favorite modal plugin, but you'll need to bind into the show/hide event on the modal dialog to show/hide your custom overlay, something that should certainly be possible.  However, the specifics of doing this vary by the plugin you choose.

Comment: Thank you,hum! sorry keep clicking return and adding more thank you's well deserved, but was going to say before I clickedd return- that I was trying onresize close then reload,bu  think maybe your way is better for my purposes. thank you!

Comment: Mamj, if my response was helpful to you, please click the checkbox next to my post so it turns green.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a problem my light box was loading under the page. The problem is that in css file including code

when the light box loading under the page 
i have written this line

```
<link  type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
```

only inculde rel="stylesheet" in link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
```

My problem is resolved